# Laravel 5.1 ajax url parameter is url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am working with Laravel 5.1 for the first time and I cannot understand why I am getting 404s on an ajax call that passes a URL to the server PHP script as a parameter.

I am executing an Ajax call that is being handled by a route as follows:

```
Route::get('ajax/{act}', ['uses' => 'AjaxController@helpers', 'as' => 'ajax.helpers']);
```

I want the variable `{act}` to hold the sring of key / value pairs I pass. I decode these in the PHP at the server end. The Ajax PHP script contains a variety of helpers and I do not want to create a Laravel rout for each.

In my app, the user will input a url in a form field, which I capture in a variable called `website`

My ajax call needs to accept:

```
var url = '/ajax/act=url&u=' + website;
```

I am doing this to build the url I then pass to a jQuery `$.getJSON` call:

```
var url = '/ajax/act=url&&u=' + encodeURIComponent(website);
```

I would expect the `encodeURIcompponent()` function to make this work, but it returns `404` when any of the parameters contain `/` characters prior to the `encodeURIComponent()`. My base url works perfectly without the additional url as a parameter.

But passing a url as a variable value, it throws 404.

This is what the url in ajax call looks like that returns 404:

```
http://my.app/ajax/act=url&u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

This url works perfectly (I have removed the `//` from `http://google.com`:

```
http://my.app/ajax/act=url&u=http%3Agoogle.com
```

It also fails when there is additional path items in the variable url as it contains additional `/` characters, like as follows:

```
http://google.com/subfolder
```

How do I pass the full url as a parameter in the ajax call? Thanks!

Comment: You mean the second url that you've said works, returns some kind of response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing route parameters and query parameters. Your route is defined as `ajax/{action}`. In this case, `{action}` is a route parameter, but you're trying to stuff query parameters into it.

For example, if you access the url `http://my.app/ajax/act=url&u=google.com`, this will work because you've hit the route `ajax/{action}`, where `{action}` is `act=url&u=google.com`. That is the value that will get passed to your `AjaxController@helpers` function. However, since this data is passed in as a route parameter, it is not in the request input. `$request->all()` will be empty.

However, if you access the url `http://my.app/ajax/act=url&u=http://google.com`, this will not work, as you do not have this route defined. This does not map to the `ajax/{action}` route; this route would be mapped to `ajax/{action}//google.com`, which you do not have defined (hence the 404).

I think what you're really looking for is this: `http://my.app/ajax/url?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com`. This will hit your `ajax/{action}` route with `url` as the `{action}` route parameter and the url value will be in the query parameters. Inside your `AjaxController@helpers` function, you can access the url via `$request->input('u');`.

### Edit

If you really need this data to come in as a route parameter, another option you have to make sure your route parameter consumes everything, including slashes:

```
Route::get('ajax/{action}', ['uses' => 'AjaxController@helpers', 'as' => 'ajax.helpers'])
    ->where('action', '.*');
```

If you do this, however, this route will catch everything that falls under `http://my.app/ajax/...`.

Comment: Hi @patricus I understand. Let me try!

Comment: @TheRealPapa That encoding doesn't matter. The Laravel router decodes the url before parsing it. You can't have slashes in route parameters (encoded or not).

Comment: @TheRealPapa I have added another alternative for you to try, if you really need the data as a route parameter vs query parameter.

Comment: I just built it like your first suggestion (which makes a lot of sense) but I get an error where the code ties to assign a value from $request. The $request->input('u') fails, and $request contains an instance of a class and not any of the parameter values

Comment: @TheRealPapa That's really a new question. Can you post a new question showing the updated route and the controller code? Comment here to let me know when you've posted it so I can try to help. Also, if you feel this answer answered your original question, please mark it as such, so that future searchers can know at a glance it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are using *relative* paths with your url variable (as you've a leading `/` in your URL), that could be causing the `404` not found error.

Try storing your `base url` using Laravel's helper method `url()` in a hidden field in your view (you could do it in your *master* view if you wanted).

```
<input id='baseUrl' type='hidden' value='{{ url() }}' />
```

You can grab the value as simple as creating a JS helper function as such:

```
var baseUrl = function(){
    return $('#baseUrl').val();
};
```

Then append that url into the beginning of your variable `url` like so:

```
var url = baseUrl() + '/ajax/act=url&&u=' + encodeURIComponent(website);
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thanks for the reply. The url is being entered by a user in a form field. The Ajax is for checking its validity and that it meets certain format requirements. I need to pull the url from the input and pass it to a server script. Laravel does not generate the url for me. I think I may not have been clear enough in my question. I will ammend. Did I misunderstand your suggestion?